# What is the procedure when allocating reviews to users

Tags: support, review

I am just curious, on how we get the reviews and how do we get allocated to review questions in Stack Overflow?

Does it get assigned randomly?

Comment: As far as I'm aware (hence this is a comment not an answer), once you have the rep to see each of the review types then you get to see everything meeting that criteria. Nothing is 'asssigned' to people to review specifically, just as soon as a post is made that requires review then it's added to the list.

Comment: oh ok I only got to review once or twice and when ever I check its always empty .. so i was wondering whether its being assigned by someone

Comment: No, I think that probably means that people have already gotten to the reviews before you had the chance to.

Comment: I find it weird that sometimes it's empty for 5 minutes then suddenly gets 15 posts in there - is this caching or deliberate?

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy never seen such a thing, doubt that review items are cached. You remember what queue exactly?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: for example Suggested Edits, there will be about 6 there then (refreshes 2 seconds after previous) about 50 suggested edits there.  Same, but not as extreme on other empty queues.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy suggested edits are different, as sometimes there will be "boost" of edits indeed, e.g. single user going on retag spree which can be done really fast. Anyway, looks like valid behavior and nothing we should worry about.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Think of it this way:

[image]

Comment: That image is just silly, why is nobody getting slapped during the process?

Comment: @PeterJ you can't see this, but a boy who failed an audit got slapped in the back of the class. :D

Comment: Well that's OK then :)

Comment: The Stack Overflow system is female?

Comment: @James of course, you didn't know that??

Comment: Freehand red arrows instead of freehand red circles? This is madness!

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I did not! I shall be more careful in my cursing it from now on when something bugs me! (I wanted to make the joke about it explaining a few things, but it's just, not appropriate. and I'd appear sexist, which I am not)

Comment: @Wooble I considered circling her head but it didn't look well so went on Plan B. ;)

Comment: @James you mean curse starting with "son"? :D